# The output is same with "OR" and "AND" Python Operators

Tags: python, for-loop

I created an alphabet B by using python for the loop.

```
for row in range(7):
    for col in range(5):
        if (col==0 or col==4) or ((row==0 or row==3 or row==6) and (col>0 and col<4)):
            print("*", end="")
        else:
            print(end=" ")  
print()
```

In the if statement, I used Python `Or` operator, instead of `And`, in `(col>0 and col<4))`, but the output was the same. Could anyone explain the reason, please?

Comment: What values of `col` and `row` are causing it to behave the same? If you work it out on paper, how does it differ from how the code is behaving?

Comment: `I created a letter B` - what does it mean?

Comment: @Alderven, I think this prints ASCII art that looks like the letter B

Comment: `(col>0 or col<4)` will always be true.

Comment: If `(col==0 or col==4)` is `True` the remaining part of your condition is not evaluated.

Comment: what values of col can satisfy (col==0 or col==4) ? 
what values of col can satisfy (col>0 and col<4) ?

Comment: `and (col>0 and col<4)` is not needed

Comment: @Alderven I mean the alphabet  B

Answer (score 1):

Well, if `col` is in `range(5)`, it means it can be either 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. That means that the only cases in which `col > 0 and col < 4` doesn't have the exact same truth table as `col > 0 or col < 4` are when `col == 0` or `col == 4`. Both of these cases are short-circuited by the 1st part of your expression (in the first parenthesis) so it is never checked for in the 2nd part.